# Making asynchronous ajax requests rather than synchronous loops

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, asynchronous

I am requesting data by Ajax from an api which provides a long array of identity codes. Each of these codes is then used in the query string to request related data from a second api. I have done this by looping with the following jQuery which works but seems very inefficient. While the initial request must be made first, the requests to the second api are each being made synchronously, I imagine this can be done asynchronously (perhaps using deferred object ?) but I have been unable to get my head around how to do this. I'd really appreciate some guidance.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://url.com/api1",
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(result){
        $.each( result, function(key, val) {
            $.each( val.SubGroups, function(key, val) {
                $.each( val.SubGroups, function(key, val) {
                    console.log(val.Group_Description);
                    $.each( val.Requirements, function(key, val) {
                        let reqid = val.Requirement_ID;
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "GET",
                            url: "https://url.com/api2?Req_ID=" + reqid,
                            contentType: "application/json",
                            dataType: "json",
                            success: function(operations){
                                console.log(operations.Name);
                                console.log(operations.Symbol);
                                console.log(operations.Hours);
                            }
                        })
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    }
})
</script>
```

json api1 looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "SubGroups": [
            {
                "SubGroups": [
                    {
                        "Group_Description": "Description1",
                        "Requirements": [
                            { "Requirement_ID": "123" },
                            { "Requirement_ID": "456" },
                            { "Requirement_ID": "789" }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "Group_Description": "Description2",
                        "Requirements": [
                            { "Requirement_ID": "123" },
                            { "Requirement_ID": "456" },
                            { "Requirement_ID": "789" }
                        ]
                    },
                ]
            }
        ],
    }
],
```

json api2 looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "Name": 1,
        "Symbol": "\u0000",
        "Hours": 2
    }
]
```

Comment: If you can, I would change the api instead as it would be more efficient

Comment: *"...the requests to the second api are each being made synchronously..."* What makes you think that? The code shown does the first API call, then when it completes fires of a bunch of calls to the second API. Those requests will be processed asynchronously and in parallel unless the **server** serializes them in some way (which some server processes do, particularly when session handling is involved). So if you're really seeing them done synchronously, the solution is server-side, not client-side (and yes, probably involves making the second API accept a batch of IDs all at once).

Comment: but, you ARE making asynchronous ajax requests - browsers may limit the number of in-flight requests to a domain at any one time, so it may appear "syncrhonous", but (as the first A in AJAX stands for Asynchronous) those requests are made asynchronously

Comment: [^^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77905983/making-asynchronous-ajax-requests-rather-than-synchronous-loops#comment137344917_77905983) Indeed, the server may be serializing them and/or the browser may be limiting the number of concurrent requests to the same server. See [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985431/max-parallel-http-connections-in-a-browser), but note the specific numbers may be out of date.

Comment: Many thanks everyone. I think it must be limitations of the browser that makes the results appear to come in staggered.